# Python progressbar http request

Tags: python, progress-bar, command-line-interface

In my simple CLI application, the app makes a http request that takes some seconds to return json values.

I'm looking for a way to cretate a progress bar for this process. I looked at tqdm and progressbar2, but I couldn't find a way to link the progress bar over the http request.

is there any way ? How?

Thanks

Comment: What library do you use to make the http request?

Comment: I'm currently using urllib2